# How do I write this, so the program restarts after the user entered his name

Tags: c#

The program asks for a name and I want the program to ask, after generating a random number, if the user wants to do it again. If the user presses  <kbd>Y</kbd> the program should restart.

```
 while (true) { 
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int trust = rnd.Next(0, 100);            
            Console.WriteLine("Tell me your name");
            string name = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(name +" " + "is" + " " + trust + " " + "points `enter code here`trustworthy");



            if (trust <= 20)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("gtfo");
            }

            if (trust >= 21 && trust <= 50)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("not gonna tell you anything");
            }

            if (trust >= 50 && trust <= 70)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("not that trustworthy");
            }

            if (trust >= 71 && trust <= 90)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("quite trustworthy");
            }

            if (trust >= 91 && trust <= 100)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" you are trustworthy");
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
            Console.WriteLine("\nAgain? (y/n)");
            if (Console.ReadLine().ToLower() != "yes")
                    break;
            }
```

Comment: You can try declaring a bool (ex. `bool restart = true;`) *before* the loop. Instead of a `while(true)` , it should then be `while(restart != false)`.

Comment: what is the problem with current code ?  It seems if you enter "yes" then it should continue the loop.

Comment: @ManojChoudhari , wouldn't `break;` *exit* the `while` loop?

Comment: If you want to continue when they enter "y" then you need to check for that instead of "yes"

Comment: Take the "What's your name" part out of the loop if you don't want to ask that every time.

Comment: @Symon Correct it exits if the user enters anything other than "yes"

Comment: @Symon  - i was telling the same thing.  If user enters yes then the loop will continue.  Otherwise it will break.  If this program should continue the loop if y is pressed, then there should be one OR (||) condition to check with 'y' also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things you can fix in your code.

1. The exit condition for the loop (where you call `break;`) should be if the user does **NOT** enter "yes" (you have it break if they **do** enter "yes").
2. If you only want to ask for the user's name once, take that part out of the loop
3. You should only declare one instance of `Random` rather than instantiating a new one on each loop iteration, so we can take that out of the loop also.
4. You can use `else if` since the conditions are all exclusive - no need to process all the rest of the conditions if we hit a `true` one
5. You can use [string interpolation](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi04rKmyIThAhWNv54KHdTqCo8QFjAAegQICxAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fdotnet%2Fcsharp%2Flanguage-reference%2Ftokens%2Finterpolated&usg=AOvVaw1h9uetT2HpoCxIBz41E4IG) to make the output string a little more readable
6. We can allow the user to enter 'y' instead of "yes" by using `Console.ReadKey`

These things implemented would look something like:

```
Console.WriteLine("Tell me your name");
string name = Console.ReadLine();
Random rnd = new Random();

while (true)
{
    int trust = rnd.Next(0, 100);
    Console.WriteLine($"{name} is {trust} points trustworthy");

    if (trust <= 20) Console.WriteLine("gtfo");
    else if (trust <= 50) Console.WriteLine("not gonna tell you anything");
    else if (trust <= 70) Console.WriteLine("not that trustworthy");
    else if (trust <= 90) Console.WriteLine("quite trustworthy");
    else Console.WriteLine("you are trustworthy");

    Console.WriteLine("\nAgain? (y/n)");

    if (Console.ReadKey().Key != ConsoleKey.Y) break;
}
```